# PHONEGAP, CORDOVA HTTP POST, GET No funciona en Android 8 y 9

Tags: jquery, android, angular, phonegap, http-get

Al realizar llamadas mediante http POST o GET no funciona.

Error: ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED, ERR CLEARTEXT NOT PERMITTED

```
$.ajax({
                url:'http://some-domain.com/account.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify({"some": $rootScope.some}),
                processData: false,
                success: function (data) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Habilita el poder usar urls no cifradas (`android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` ) dentro de tu archivo config.xml :

```
<platform name="android">
  <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
      <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
  </edit-config>
</platform>
```